# Fastest React Virtual List component?

Tags: reactjs, list, performance, scroll

I'm currently using [`react-window`](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-window) which, as far as I understand, is an evolution of [`react-virtualized`](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized) but I am running into low framerates when scrolling through lists of mildly complex items.

Alongside optimizing the DOM of the list items I'm rendering, I'm trying to find an alternative implementation with a strong focus on performance. So far I've encountered:

- [React Virtuoso](https://virtuoso.dev/)
- [Adobe's useListBox](https://react-spectrum.adobe.com/react-aria/useListBox.html)

I haven't had a chance to try either of these alternatives yet. Before I spend time porting my code over, I'd like to find out whether other libraries exist that have a proven track record.